# Dual screens on Ubuntu with Dell IPS monitors

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor

I have an old desktop with only one display port, and one VGA. Unfortunately my Dell IPS monitors only support DP and HDMI input. The monitor also has a DP out port, so I connected the monitors to one another. Is it possible (My brother said he did it on Windows) to get Ubuntu to treat this setup as two monitors instead of just duplicating the display?

I tried looking it up online but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess I wasn't clear enough - of course I tried it, the question came after it didn't work.

Anyway, it turns out that my graphic card was DP 1.1, and daisy chaining is only available as of DP 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way to find out, right?

I don't see a problem with that, the system will notice the difference between the two connectors. Check Displays in System Settings to make any adjustments.

Try it!